# Strange Angular issue concerning multiple directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm new to the project I'm working on and have been tasked to debug an error that's been put aside for so long no one remembers when it came up. I don't even know how or where to begin debugging this.

The issue is as such: We have multiple states in our project using ui-router.
The first time I open a state called insight everything works fine.
When I transition to another state called live everything works fine.
However when I now transition back to insight I get an error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [, select] asking for 'select' controller on: <select class="form-control" name="entities_type" ng-model="entity_types.signature" ng-options="entity_type.signature for entity_type in entity_types.available">
```

and if I go back to live I get the error:

```
Multiple directives [, select] asking for 'select' controller on: <select class="input" ng-model="event_group" name="event_group">
```

As I said before both views work fine on the first load.

The code for the selects is as follows:

Live:

```
<fieldset>
    <section class="col col-6 no-padding">
        <label class="label">Event Category</label>
        <label class="select">
            <select class="input" ng-model="event_group" name="event_group">
                <option value="event_type">Event types</option>
                <option value="entities">Involved entities</option>
                <option value="origin">Sent from origin</option>
                <option value="analytics">Live analytics</option>
                <option value="observations">Observations</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </section>
</fieldset>
```

Insight:

```
<select class="form-control"
    name="entities_type"
    ng-model="entity_types.signature"
    ng-options="entity_type.signature for entity_type in entity_types.available">
        <option ng-value="">Filter by entity type ...</option>
</select>
```

This issue was also present while using ngRoute.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing this?